# using *ngFor with grid CSS effectively

Tags: html, css, angular, ngfor

I would like to generate a grid based on unknown rows. The grid is simple with only two columns. One column containing row labels and the other some UI element such as a checkbox.

The only way I've been able to make this work is by generating a new grid with each loop through (see example below). I would like to accomplish this with a single ngFor and a single Grid.

Clarification, each label must be on the same row as their respective checkbox.

example :

```
    <div *ngFor="let row of rows">
      <div class="popup-grid">
        <div>
          {{row.label}}
        </div>
        <div>
          <p-checkbox  "angular interactions/events here">
          </p-checkbox>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is how you would use ngFor with CSS grid effectively. You can use [ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) to prevent *ngFor from inserting divs into the dom. This will prevent generating a new grid with each loop through.

> The Angular `ng-container` is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

Then surround `ng-container` with a div with `display: grid;`. You can then use the [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) rule in order to define the amount of columns you want. Grid will automatically place rows. Check the example code below.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let row of data">
        <label>{{row}}</label>
        <div><input type="checkbox"></div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* Create 2 columns and auto-place rows */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use bootstrap CSS with html elements like

```
<section>
        <div class="row bg-light" *ngFor="let row of Rows">
            <div class="col-md-3 border cursor-action">
                <label>
                    <b>{{row.label}}</b>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 border cursor-action">
                <input type="checkbox">
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score -2):

There is only one CLEAN way to approach any layout which is the flexbox layout.

I tried and loved both of those solutions

1. Angular Flex layout, super rich implementation and easy to use apis https://github.com/angular/flex-layout
   you can also see the possibilities here https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

2- Bootstrap Grid system https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

that's not a short answer but if u adopt any of them you will never ever have to struggle with layout again.

Cheers!

---

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row"
       *ngFor="let row of rows;let i = index;">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-xxxx">
      <label for="cb{{i}}">some label</label>
      <input id="cb{{i}}"
             type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I would still like an answer to my question or a more detailed response as to why it is not possible to execute 'CLEANLY' .

Comment: The "only one" remark is not accurate. However flex is one of them that's most adopted.

Comment: @Keegan When u work on an enterprise level applications, the last thing u want is inconsistency, what i noticed in my little experience is that devs tend to write tons of CSS to create simple layouts, my role is NEVER write CSS code for layout, and when u have to, do it but know in yourself that something is not right and there will be a cost for that, a library like Angular Flex layout when utilized properly it reduces CSS in projects drastically, eliminating inconsistency and unexpected layout behaviours  specially when there is a need for responsive design.